# Word for being sad because you love something so much but know that ultimately it will end but you still give it all your love

Tags: single-word-requests

I heard a word that basically means being sad because you love something so much but know that ultimately it will end but you still give it all your love. Like loving someone and showering them with it because you love them so much even though you know you’ll eventually run out of time with them. I was wondering if anyone knew this word.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example of a sentence you'd like to use this word in?

Comment: Perhaps investigate words that focus on different kinds of grief, because this sounds like a person mourning in advance of their loss. The showering of love is the compulsion to overcompensate based on that foreknowledge. It's a complicated concept. Also, don't despair of the answers you will get on this forum. There is little understanding here that English is constantly evolving.

Comment: I don't think English will have a dedicated term for "love" (whatever exactly that means) accentuated by the knowledge that the object of one's affections is ephemeral (the lover will outlast the loved). But there's a well-established more general term: [**bittersweet**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bittersweet) - *containing a mixture of sadness and happiness.*

Comment: An *elegiac* view of life is mournful because *everything* comes to an end.  In your case, you seem to be saying that the sadness comes from the knowledge that something in particular must come to an end. So I'd upvote **bittersweet**.

Comment: Best I can do is "poignant"

Answer (score 0):

The following list may not include the desired word, but is presented in the hope it may help jog the memory and lead to the right one:

- bereaved (saddened due to being deprived of a loved one)
- distressed (anxiety, sorrow, pain)
- vexed (archaic usage: distressed)
- grieved
- lovelorn (unhappy due to unrequited or unreturned love)
- unrequited (not returned or rewarded--used of a feeling, esp. love)
- heartsick (grieved by great loss, typically of a loved one)
- nostalgic (sentimental feelings toward happy memories)
- compassionate (feeling or showing sympathy toward someone)
- clinging (hanging on dearly regardless of consequences)
- *[hesed](https://firmisrael.org/learn/the-meaning-of-hesed-hebrew-for-love/)* (Hebrew word for unconditional, enduring love: includes concepts of compassion, faithfulness, and mercy)